# Unable to pass encrypted text to .net web service

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, encryption, des

I'm working on a `web service` based system which has a Client who encrypts a text using `DES` algorithm.

When my client sends the encrypted text to a web method on the web service, I catch a

> *ProtocolException exception saying The remote server returned an unexpected response: (400) Bad Request.*

Text before encryption : "Hello"
Text after encryption : "I%�l�*�"

What should I do to solve the issue?

Comment: The result of encryption is *binary data*. Use hex or base64 to represent it as text.

Comment: Thanks @JonSkeet :) base64 did it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exception occurred due to special characters in string which is not supported.
You can make change in service to accept stream in place of string.

Server side code :

```
Boolean GetData(Stream fStream)
{
    try 
    {           
    // Read the stream into a byte array

    Byte[] data  = new Byte[32767];
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
            while(true)
            {
                    Int32 read = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
                    if(read <= 0)
                        return ms.ToArray();
                    ms.Write(data, 0, read);
            }
    }

    // Copy to a string for header parsing
    String content = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);

    // do something
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    throw(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Smmer thanks for your reply, could you help me with a sample code snippet? A: How should I convert my string to a stream. B: How should I change my web service to accept stream?